# Everything is Aligned left

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I’ve tried the content-fluid tag as well as the meta tag `<meta name=“viewport” content=“width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1” />`

You can check it out here: emotesheaven.com/dev1987 for a live example of the issue occurring as I can’t post images. I find it strange as the website on desktop looks fine, but only on my iPhone 7 it appears weird. Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with the website? I see it works fine, what is specifically aligned left?

Comment: It’s only on my iPhone, no idea if it’s just me, but you can see the text at the top is cut off, so you gotta zoom out to see the whole page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the title text add this to your code.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 780px){
.intro .intro-title {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
}
```

Comment: I tried adjusting to your parameters, but it doesn't work. Thank you though! It does resize the text, however the rest of the page is the issue, not the nav bar and intro text. (If you're on mobile device, try to zoom out and scroll down to see what I mean)

Comment: I have checked it an only i have found this error. maybe its just happening to your iphone :/

Comment: I just checked on my wifes iphone and it appears it is just my phone. Your solution worked, thank you so much! Maybe its an issue with ios 13?

Comment: my plasure . might be you need to write some extra code for ios compatibility .